# Using a For Loop to Sort and Save Files Using Grep

Tags: bash, grep, for

I have a huge number of files that are numbered in a way such as `file_01_01.out` where the first number is the group that the file belongs to, and the second is number of the file in the group - so `file_10_07.out` is the 7th file in the 10th group.

I want to copy some text from these files and group them in some output files. I have tried using this and it doesn't really work, and I can't understand why:

```
for i in {0..21};
  do
    grep "text" file_$i_*out > out_$i.txt;
done;
```

Not sure why this doesn't work, but there is definitely logic to the output. It's just not the output I was going for, and some files are just completely skipped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(in adition to @Philippos): Bash is trying to expand variable `$i_` instead of `$i`.
Try `...${i}_...`:

```
for i in {00..21}
  do     
    grep "text" file_${i}_*out > out_$i.txt
  done
```

Answer (score 5):

Your pattern will expand to `file_1_`, but you need `file_01_`

Use `for i in {00..21};`

Comment: @ Phillippos: cool! (+1)

Comment: Also see @JJoao's answer: Another problem is that the underscore is a valid variable name character, so you need to use `${i}`. I shouldn't have stopped at the first problem I saw! (-: